# .htaccess not working in linux server

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, .htaccess, windows-server-2012

Actually my project is in WordPress. I'm changing my server from windows to Linux.

After changing this I'm facing this error!

Why isn't my `.htaccess` supporting the Linux server?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Have you configured your Apache Server on Linux? .htaccess files have to be allowed using `AllowOverride`. This [directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride) allows you to use .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org), you should configure it in order to allow .htaccess files to be executed.

To do so, you can

- Create a [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/examples.html), that configures specifically one site. Using a virtual host you can set a domain name, document root, server alias, etc. Also, you can set `Allowoverride` to `All` (or other). See [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
- Set your [configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/configuring.html) in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` (or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` in some versions). In these files, there is a `<Directory "/var/www/"` that points to your /var/www/ directory. Inside this Directory tag, you can set `AllowOverride` to `All`. Using this configuration, every site on your server will be allowed to use .htaccess.

I recommend to use the Virtual Host that allows a easier and cleaner configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the comment in .htaccess file, if it starts with **//** then change it to **#**

For me this solved the problem, I wish for you too.